# Android unable to copy image to another folder

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I have created two folders in my phone.One has an image.Upon button click I want to copy from one folder to another.I get a FileNotFoundException eventhough I check if it exists.I have declared the permission as well.Below is the code.Please find the mistake I have done.

Java Class:

```
 File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/File1");
                      File internalfle=new File(file+"/Bronze.jpg");
                      File tocopy=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/File2");
                      if (internalfle.exists())
                          {
                            if (tocopy.exists())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                try {
                                    InputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(internalfle.getAbsolutePath());
                                    OutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(tocopy.getAbsolutePath());
                                    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
                                    int len;
                                    while ((len=fileInputStream.read(buffer))>0)
                                    {
                                        outputStream.write(buffer,0,len);
                                    }
                                    fileInputStream.close();
                                    outputStream.close();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Copied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                          }
                          else
                          {
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Does not Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
```

Exception:

```
06-02 20:06:41.782 23544-23544/com.globemaster.com.test W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/File2: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
        at com.globemaster.com.test.MainActivity$1$override.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
06-02 20:06:41.792 23544-23544/com.globemaster.com.test W/System.err:     at com.globemaster.com.test.MainActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
        at com.globemaster.com.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
06-02 20:06:41.792 23544-23544/com.globemaster.com.test W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is caused because there is no file named 'File2' *FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/File2: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)*. By the looks of it, 'File2' is a directory.

You must provide a valid path in your code (note the subtle: **"/File2/BronzeCopy.jpg"**):

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/File1");
File internalfle=new File(file+"/Bronze.jpg");
File tocopy=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/File2/BronzeCopy.jpg");
```

The following code just makes sure the File exists **(but it can also be a directory)**

```
if (tocopy.exists())
```

Therefore, what you intend is something like:

```
if (tocopy.exists() && !tocopy.isDirectory())
```

You also must handle the case in which the 'tocopy' path is not valid for providing a reliable solution.

Comment: So I should give a name to the image to be copied to another folder(BronzeCopy.jpg)

Comment: Yes.That was the problem.Thank you.

Comment: Exactly, to be precise you should have another method which handles this in order to avoid hardcoded names 'Bronze' -> 'BronzeCopy'

Comment: "You also must handle the case in which the 'tocopy' path is not valid for providing a reliable solution."What did u mean by this?